# Python can't access cmd when using CX_FREEZE

Tags: python, cmd, cx-freeze

After I build my script using CX_FREEZE I can't get anything to print. 
Tried using shell :

```
cmd ="echo %s"% a
call(cmd, shell=True)
```

But that didn't worked either. Is there another way to open CMD and print something after building. I'm using 3.6 python and using 32 bit.